# array_key_exists() error / edit a vendor file

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, vendor

I have a small problem in my laravel API deployed in heroku, that started to happen to me from nowhere, without updating anything or making any relevant changes, and it happens to me when I try to use any eloquent resource, for example when doing:

```
$brands = Brand::paginate(15);
return BrandResource::collection($brands);
```

I get this error:

> array_key_exists(): Using array_key_exists() on objects is deprecated. Use isset() or property_exists() instead
>
> in DelegatesToResource.php line 49

Investigating a bit, get to the file: `DelegatesToResource.php` in `vendor`, and in effect it use:

```
 public function offsetExists($offset)
{
    return array_key_exists($offset, $this->resource);
}
```

To make a test, I created a new Laravel project, and in fact it comes with that line already corrected, like this:

```
public function offsetExists($offset)
{
    return isset($this->resource[$offset]);
}
```

If there is any way to solve this in my project, I understand that I should not and cannot change files in `vendor`, so my question is what to do in this case?

I´m using Laravel Framework 5.6.39 and PHP 7.2.18 (cli)

Comment: You know how to change it, so do.  If you can't or won't change it then adjust error reporting wherever you have it `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED`

Comment: try upgrading your laravel. Your version is 1-2 year old...

Comment: another way , is to download the package locally , and change it . in your composer.json , your must reffer to the package locally.

Comment: I check some of the last commits in github repo of laravel source code they already fix this issue: 
    `public function offsetExists($offset)`
   ` {`
   `   -  return array_key_exists($offset, $this->resource);`
   `   +  return isset($this->resource[$offset]);`
 `  }  `

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

Add updated code to your `BrandResource` so it may appear like this:

```
class BrandResource extends JsonResource
{
     /**
     * Determine if the given attribute exists.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $offset
     * @return bool
     */
    public function offsetExists($offset)
    {
        return isset($this->resource[$offset]);
    }

    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

**Solution 2**

If you are paginating your data in multiple resources then it's better to extend custom class which contains this updated function rather than extending `JsonResource` directly.
So it'll look like this:

```
class CustomResource extends JsonResource
{
     /**
     * Determine if the given attribute exists.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $offset
     * @return bool
     */
    public function offsetExists($offset)
    {
        return isset($this->resource[$offset]);
    }
}
```

And Use on your resources like:

```
class BrandResource extends CustomResource
    {
        /**
         * Transform the resource into an array.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @return array
         */
        public function toArray($request)
        {
            return parent::toArray($request);
        }
    }
```